# How to prevent Panda's itertuple method from adding extra decimals to records from a csv file? -Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a Python function that reads through a csv file and returns each row in the csv in a tuple.

I'm using Python's Pandas library to achieve this.

The problem is after Pandas returns the tuple, it appends an extra decimal point to records that looks like an integer. e.g `1001 becomes 1001.0`

Sample csv file:

```
key1, key2
a, '1001'
b, '2002'
```

The code is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file_content_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file)

for each_row in file_content_df.itertuples():
    row_item1, row_item2 = each_row
    print row_item1  # Prints 'a'
    print row_item2  # Prints 1001.0 (Desired result is 1001)
```

Is there a way to control this behavior pls ?!

Answer (score 0):

First you can check [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) if column `key2` is `int` or `float` or `object` and then you can use second item by `each_row[1]` and third item by `each_row[2]`:

```
print df
  key1  key2
0    a  1001
1    b  2002

print df.dtypes
key1    object
key2     int64
dtype: object

for each_row in df.itertuples():
    print each_row
    print each_row[1]
    print each_row[2]
    print '******'

Pandas(Index=0, key1='a', key2=1001)
a
1001
******
Pandas(Index=1, key1='b', key2=2002)
b
2002
******
```

If `dtypes` of column `key2` is `object` and `df` is like:

```
print df
  key1    key2
0    a  '1001'
1    b  '2002'

print df.dtypes
key1    object
key2    object
dtype: object

#remove ' and cast to integer
df['key2'] = df['key2'].str.strip("'").astype(int)

print df.dtypes
key1    object
key2     int32
dtype: object

for each_row in df.itertuples():
    print each_row
    print each_row[1]
    print each_row[2]
    print '******'

Pandas(Index=0, key1='a', key2=1001)
a
1001
******
Pandas(Index=1, key1='b', key2=2002)
b
2002
******
```